# mysql is not starting on wampserver

Tags: mysql, wampserver

i had to solve some errors the first time i download wampserver but when i solved all the errors mysql server still not working !! soo i tried to follow some youtube fixing and i end up finding out that mysql.log is empty i don't know if this is normal !! and i consulted the resource monitor and i found out that mysql is not in the right port ( it's suppose to be in 3306 but it's in 3307 and not allowed ) i tested the port and nothing  [image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well MySql can be configured on both ports. Usually 1st priority is on 3306 and if needed another instance then on 3307. You may check if the service is running for port 3307. If you find it difficulty running service then try deleting log for 3307.

Comment: the service is not running and when i try to start it i get an error saying that it started and then stopped automatically cause it might not be used by another services or programs, it's really tricky i don't know what to do with it

Comment: Try deleting log files from port 3307 MySql data folder. It should start.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it !! it seems that the last version of wampserver ( 3.1 ) wasn't working for me soo i tried to download wamps 2.5 and it worked like magic !! i guess the maria DB was blocking mysql or something and since the wamps 2.5 doesn't have it it worked